# Sharing one model between two views that display different columns of data

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, model-view, qabstractitemmodel

In this case, I am working with legacy code. I have a large dequeue data structure. This is the data source. I need two `QTableView` widgets on a single dialog that utilize the same data source but show different columns of data. Since each table displays different columns of data, how can they share the same `QAbstractItemModel`? Is this what proxy models are for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proxy models  (`QSortFilterProxyModel` or `QAbstractProxyModel`) are for filtering, sorting or other data processing tasks. In your case you should use the same model for two different views and just hide the unnecessary columns in each view :

```
QTableView *tableView = new QTableView();
QTableView *secondtableView = new QTableView();

MyModel *model = new MyModel();

tableView->setModel(model);
secondtableView->setModel(model);

tableView->setColumnHidden(0, true);
secondtableView->setColumnHidden(2, true);
secondtableView->setColumnHidden(3, true);

QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
layout->addWidget(tableView);
layout->addWidget(secondtableView);
```